# Basic way to clean url from normal url

Tags: web-development, php

I want to make clean URL from normal URL:

```
// Normal URL
home.php?kategori=dress

// Clean URL
home.php/dress
```

How could I build clean URL like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [mod_rewrite](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=mod+rewrite+tuto&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mod_rewrite+tutorial)